# Defining a function which takes lists as it arguments and threads over them

Tags: list-manipulation, variable

I want to define a function with lists as variables, which has the form like

```
m = Table[2, {i, 5}];
f[x_, y_] = m*x + x*y;
```

x and y are list variables; m is a constant list with same dimension. If I evaluate this function at

```
xx = Table[1, {i, 5}]; yy = Table[1, {i, 5}];
```

I want the output to be

```
m*xx + xx*yy
```

which is

```
{3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

But in fact if I run the function

```
f[xx, yy]
```

I will get

```
{{3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}}
```

This is not the result I want. I have tried

```
f @@ {xx, yy}
```

and

```
f /@ {xx, yy}
```

Neither one works. How should I fix fix this problem?

Comment: It should be `f[x_, y_] := m*x + x*y` … colon is needed.

Comment: Just check what `m*x` evaluates to, to see why, and read [Understand the difference between Set (or `=`) and SetDelayed (or `:=`)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/18476) for more informations.

Comment: This  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236808) of mine may also be somewhat relevant.